# Install GNOME on Gentoo

Tags: gnome, gentoo

I want to choose more convenient desktop environment than i3. I'm trying install GNOME from overlay dantell-gnome-3-24. I use OpenRC init system. However, when I try emerge GNOME I'm receiving error:

```
tux ~ # emerge --ask --verbose --keep-going gnome-base/gnome

 * IMPORTANT: 16 news items need reading for repository 'gentoo'.
 * Use eselect news read to view new items.


These are the packages that would be merged, in order:

Calculating dependencies... done!

emerge: there are no ebuilds built with USE flags to satisfy "net-misc/curl[ssl,curl_ssl_nss]".
!!! One of the following packages is required to complete your request:
- net-misc/curl-7.57.0::gentoo (Change USE: +curl_ssl_nss, this change violates use flag constraints defined by net-misc/curl-7.57.0: 'curl_ssl_winssl? ( elibc_Winnt ) threads? ( !adns ) ssl? ( exactly-one-of ( curl_ssl_axtls curl_ssl_gnutls curl_ssl_libressl curl_ssl_mbedtls curl_ssl_nss curl_ssl_openssl curl_ssl_winssl ) )')
(dependency required by "net-libs/liboauth-1.0.3::gentoo[nss,curl]" [ebuild])
(dependency required by "dev-libs/libgdata-0.17.9-r1::dantrell-gnome" [ebuild])
(dependency required by "gnome-extra/california-0.4.0-r1::dantrell-gnome" [ebuild])
(dependency required by "gnome-base/gnome-extra-apps-3.24.0::dantrell-gnome-3-24[california]" [ebuild])
(dependency required by "gnome-base/gnome-3.24.0::dantrell-gnome-3-24[extras]" [ebuild])
(dependency required by "gnome-base/gnometux ~ # emerge --ask --verbose --keep-going gnome-base/gnome

 * IMPORTANT: 16 news items need reading for repository 'gentoo'.
 * Use eselect news read to view new items.


These are the packages that would be merged, in order:

Calculating dependencies... done!

emerge: there are no ebuilds built with USE flags to satisfy "net-misc/curl[ssl,curl_ssl_nss]".
!!! One of the following packages is required to complete your request:
- net-misc/curl-7.57.0::gentoo (Change USE: +curl_ssl_nss, this change violates use flag constraints defined by net-misc/curl-7.57.0: 'curl_ssl_winssl? ( elibc_Winnt ) threads? ( !adns ) ssl? ( exactly-one-of ( curl_ssl_axtls curl_ssl_gnutls curl_ssl_libressl curl_ssl_mbedtls curl_ssl_nss curl_ssl_openssl curl_ssl_winssl ) )')
(dependency required by "net-libs/liboauth-1.0.3::gentoo[nss,curl]" [ebuild])
(dependency required by "dev-libs/libgdata-0.17.9-r1::dantrell-gnome" [ebuild])
(dependency required by "gnome-extra/california-0.4.0-r1::dantrell-gnome" [ebuild])
(dependency required by "gnome-base/gnome-extra-apps-3.24.0::dantrell-gnome-3-24[california]" [ebuild])
(dependency required by "gnome-base/gnome-3.24.0::dantrell-gnome-3-24[extras]" [ebuild])
(dependency required by "gnome-base/gnome" [argument])
" [argument])
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Take a close look at the use flags for `net-misc/curl` on your system and adjust them to resolve the blockage.

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable the `ssl` USE flag on `curl`